# Why does Git have a Workspace, Staging Area, and Local Repository?

Tags: git

I am trying to understand why Git has so many places to store changes. Imagine a simpler Git model that has only a local repository (and not a separate staging area or workspace). In this model:

1. We could pick files in the local repository we want Git to track
2. We could track changes by taking snapshots of the repository at different points in time
3. We could fetch changes to origin/master and merge as usual
4. We could have multiple branches and switch between them
5. We could push changes from the local repository to "origin" as usual

In other words, we could do most of what Git now does, but without the conceptual clutter of a workspace, staging area, and local repository. Why is it useful to have all three?

Comment: It's not clear what you consider different places to store changes.

Comment: I consider the workspace, the staging area, and the local repo three different places to store changes. In the workspace, you store changes in a file; in the staging area, as tracked changes; in the local repo, as commits.

Comment: You can ignore the staging area if you never use `git add` to build a commit from a subset of local changes, and the distinction between the local repo and the workspace is pretty much fundamental to the entire concept of source control. What exactly do you want to get rid of?

Comment: I don't want to get rid of anything. I want to understand why it's useful to have a workspace and a staging area. You say the distinction between the workspace and a local repo is "fundamental" to source control. Can you give an example of why this distinction is useful?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There have been **tomes** written on git. Maybe what's missing for you are concrete examples of when a workspace and staging area would be useful.

### Working tree / Work tree

1) You're working on this nifty idea for a few minutes, but it's not quite ready for your local repository. After a few min of tinkering, you realise it just isn't gunna work. You can simply `git reset` your workspace to the local repository.

If you'd worked directly on the local repo, you'd have i) have dirtied your commit history, and ii) have to deal with a rollback.

2) Alternatively, say you want to merge two potentially conflicting branches. You can `git merge --no-commit`, then clean-up manually within the workspace before staging and committing to the local repo.

### Staging area

1) You've hammered-out a bug-fix in your workspace. Looking at the backlog however, you realise the bug-fix is *really* in two conceptual parts, addressing two distinct underlying issues.

Having a staging area allows you to 'stage' first half the bug fix, and commit that to your local. Then, you can 'stage' the second half of the bug fix, and commit that separately.

2) Alternatively, take the example where you've made changes to a single file. Using the staging area you can commit just one portion of that file (via a patch) to the local repository. All changes would be in the 'workspace', but only a subset would be 'staged' for commit. I most often find myself staging partial files for READMEs and CHANGELOGs.

Comment: Thank you, these are helpful examples.

Comment: @nickackerman42 if the answer is sufficient, it's best practice to label answered and/or up-vote.

Comment: @nickackerman42, BTW the official Git term for what you call "workspace" is the "work tree" or "working tree". We understand you but it's better to use the native stabilized terms ;-) Please see `git help glossary`.

Comment: @nickackerman42, Also please note that Git allows you to almost completely ignore the fact the staging area exists: the `git commit` command understands the `-a` command-line option which basically tells it "commit whatever has been changed so far", so you only ever reach for `git add` when you have a *new* (not existed before) file to add. I'd stress that it's *not* the way to work--most newcomers actually appreciate the concept of these multiple Git trees after getting used to it,--just noting that there are different possibilities.

Comment: @nickackerman42 thought it'd be easier to understand if I used the OPs terminology. Updated to proper.